# Show activy after data is downloaded

Tags: android, asynchronous, task

I have an activity called SpotDetails wich is a Activity which gathers alot of information from xml and then displays it to the user.

My problem is that i would preferably show a progress dialog while the app  downloads the data and fills the SpotDetails variables. When the variables are populated i would like to show the activity and fill the TextView's.

How could i accomplish this ?

What i have now is actually two Async threads that start on the onCreate. This generates a slow UI for the user and alot of code on the activity which actually dosen't need to be there.

Update :

pr. now im not showing anything i tried to implement a ProgressDialog using the line :

```
Progress Dialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(spotDetails.getApplicationContext());
```

Note that the Async is another class than SpotDetails.

But i get a long exception :

StackOverflow wont accept the code so here it is : 
http://pastebin.com/AJqJFvMM

Comment: Use an `AsyncTask` and add an Overlay on your view. When you have finished downloading and parsing the XML, just hide that view.

Comment: Show the progress dialog on `onPreExecute()` and dismiss it on `onPostExecute()` method. What are you doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're **already fetching the information with `asyncTask`** which is the way to go, and your concern is that until the process is completed the activity is showing nothing or incomplete data, *damaging the user experience*.

To avoid this, or somewhat solve it, you could use a splashscreen that blocks the view of the ui that's not ready to be seen yet. You could do this by a simple view that's on top of the other and you can toggle its visibility from the `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` methods of your async tasks.

In other words, modify your layout so that it contains a "loading" overlay, and make it visible while loading and invisible once it's finished, by calling the `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` or `setVisibility(View.GONE)` respectively.

*Update:*

After your update, the only thing you need to change is the way you invoke the progress dialog, to something on these lines:

```
... //Inside your asyntask
ProgressDialog pDialog;
@Override
protected void onPreExecute(){
   pDialog = new ProgressDialog(YOURACTIVITY.this);
   pDialog.setMessage("Authenticating user...");
   pDialog.show();
}
```

If your AsyncTask is defined in the same class as the activity that calls it, otherways you should pass the context through the construct, and then use that context to call the progress dialog:

```
Context mContext;
public MyTask(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}
```

And then instead of `YOURACTIVITY.this` as the context on the previous code, use `mContext`.

Comment: That is the plan actullay. and i have also tried to show a ProgressDialog but i cant seem to get it right. See the edit on the question

Comment: i Figured out the ProgressDialog error by passing a context to the Async Task. Thanks for a good answer about how to solv my problem

Comment: I actually just updated it with the context issue, glad you figured it out ;)